How to have namespaces in WSDL when using SoapCore
I am trying to provide a SOAP endpoint where the body of the returned types have a specific namespace using the SoapCore library in an ASP.NET Core service.
Whatever I do, the generated WSDL seems to be missing the namespaces I define in the XML contracts.
In the Program.cs I define the SOAP endpoint:
(app as IApplicationBuilder).UseSoapEndpoint(typeof(IDummyService),
(opt) =>
{
    opt.Path = "/DummyService.svc";
    opt.Binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    opt.SoapSerializer = SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer;
});

where IDummyService is defined as
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "DummyServiceNamespace")]
public interface IDummyService
{
   [OperationContract]
   DummyDataResponse GetDummyData();
}

And the types are defined as:
[XmlType("DummyDataResponse")]
[XmlRoot("DummyDataResponse")]
public class DummyDataResponse
{
    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0020-f/3", Order = 0)]
    public DeliveryType Delivery { get; set; }
}

And
[Serializable]
[XmlType("deliveryType", Namespace="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0020-f/3")]
public class DeliveryType
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Test")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

This will give me a WSDL looking like this:
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="DummyServiceNamespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="DummyServiceNamespace" name="IDummyService">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="DummyServiceNamespace">
<xsd:element name="GetDummyData">
<xsd:complexType/>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="GetDummyDataResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DummyDataResponse" type="tns:DummyDataResponse"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="DummyDataResponse">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Delivery" type="tns:deliveryType"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="deliveryType">
<xsd:attribute name="Test" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IDummyService_GetDummyData_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDummyData"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IDummyService_GetDummyData_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDummyDataResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IDummyService">
<wsdl:operation name="GetDummyData">
<wsdl:input message="tns:IDummyService_GetDummyData_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:IDummyService_GetDummyData_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDummyService_soap" type="tns:IDummyService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetDummyData">
<soap:operation soapAction="DummyServiceNamespace/IDummyService/GetDummyData" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="IDummyService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IDummyService_soap" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IDummyService_soap">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:5058/DummyService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>

Now what I actually wanted (and expected) would have been a WSDL where the DeliveryType actually has a own schema with the target namespace ech20:http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0020-f/3. So, something like this:
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
               elementFormDefault="qualified"
               targetNamespace="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0020-f/3"
               version="3.0"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:ech20="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0020-f/3">

       <xsd:complexType name="deliveryType">
           <xsd:attribute name="Test" type="xsd:string"/>
       </xsd:complexType>
</schema>

Is this even possible?

Looking at the discussions here: https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore/issues/903 it seems as what I want is currently explicitly not possible. The only other thing I can think of doing is to simply craft the WSDL myself and add it manually like this: https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore#using-with-external-wsdl--xsd-schemas

When utilizing the SoapCore library in an ASP.NET Core service, use the XmlType attribute with the Namespace property set to the desired namespace for the DeliveryType class in order to include a specific namespace for the types in the WSDL specification. Nevertheless, creating distinct schema documents for every namespace is not supported by SoapCore. Use a different SOAP library or generate the WSDL by hand if you require distinct schema documents.
[Serializable]
[XmlType("deliveryType", Namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0020-f/3")]
public class DeliveryType
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Test")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

